# django-selectable forms validation and model forms filter queryset

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

i use django-selectable for autocomplite and i need model form validation

so i made a validation in forms.py

```
def clean(self):
    cl_title = Color.objects.values_list('title',flat=True)
    if self.cleaned_data.get('color') != cl_title:
        raise forms.ValidationError('this color is not found in the database')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

i gen an error

```
 Request Method:    POST
 Exception Type:    ValueError
 Exception Value: Cannot assign "<Color: awffawfwa>": "Color" instance isn't saved in the database.
```

it does not work
see details below

models.py

```
class Color(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('color title', max_length=100)
    user = models.CharField(User)
    description = models.TextField('description')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
    # ... some logic

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color.title
```

lookups.py

```
from selectable.base import ModelLookup
from selectable.registry import registry
from .models import Color

class ColorLookup(ModelLookup):
    model = Book
    search_fields = ('title__icontains',)

registry.register(ColorLookup)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Color
import selectable.forms as selectable
from .lookups import BookLookup

class ItemSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    color = selectable.AutoCompleteSelectField(
    lookup_class = ColorLookup,
    allow_new = True,
    label= 'select',
    required = True,
)

class Meta:
    model = Color
    fields = ('color',)

def clean(self):
    cl_title = Color.objects.values_list('title',flat=True)
    if self.cleaned_data.get('color') != cl_title:
        raise forms.ValidationError('this color is not found in the database')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

but it does not work, can your help me, how to correct this error?
thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values_list` will return a list of colors so your single value will never equal this array, you need to check your color isn't in this list (if it really is a list you need..)

You can also separate this logic into a separate clean method for color.

```
def clean_color(self):
    color = self.cleaned_data.get('color')
    cl_title = Color.objects.values_list('title',flat=True)
    if color not in cl_title:
        raise forms.ValidationError('this color is not found in the database')
    return color
```

Alternatively and probably preferred, you could just do

```
if not Color.objects.filter(title=color).exists():
```

This is a more efficient query since it doesn't return any unneeded values from the db.